# How to burn LP token using Metaplex

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js, umi

How do i burn lp token using metaplex burnv1? This is giving me the error "incorrect account owner"

```
const umi = createUmi(RPC_ENDPOINT).use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet)).use(mplTokenMetadata());

const mint = publicKey(tokenAddress);
  
await burnV1(umi, {
  mint,
  amount: parseInt(amount),
  tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)
```